# can we use multiple plugins of flutter from one Repo?

Tags: git, flutter, dart, flutter-plugin

I am stuck at this point where I have multiple plugins that I have implemented for my new flutter App.
But I want to place all these plugins in one repo and refer them as separate plugins

My plugins are

- plugin_custom1
- custom_plugin2

My repo is having the name **flutter_plugins**

If Link to my Repo is similar to the below one

https://maja.azure.com/ramraj/flutter_plugins

All the plugin folders are placed in this repo

I've tried to point to these packages similar to the following way in my Pubspec.yaml

```
plugin_custom1:
    git:
      url: https://maja.azure.com/ramraj/flutter_pluginspath=%2Fplugin_custom1
```

Then I am facing the following error when getting packages

```
(OS Error: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found an Answer

```
plugin_custom1:
    git:
      url: https://maja.azure.com/ramraj/flutter_plugins
      path:plugin_custom1
```

Kindly refer to the following documentation of Flutter
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/using-packages#dependencies-on-unpublished-packages